# How do I use fork to make linear searching more efficient on an unsorted array?

Tags: c, arrays, search, process, fork

I am trying to implement a simple iterative search function with fork() to make linear search on an unsorted array (variable size) more efficient.

If the array is small enough, say less than size 1,000 then I will not partition and simply search the entire array iteratively.

However, lets say an array size of equal to 1,000 or greater requires to be split into smaller sub-arrays, where each sub-array is no larger than 250 items.

I am also going to handle cases where the array size is not an easily divisible number, like 1777 by dividing by 250 through integer division, then searching the remaining portion of the array.

With these things in mind, 2 questions arise:

1. How can I determine the optimal sub-array size when the array size exceeds 1000?
2. How can I make use of fork() so that this implementation of iterative search is more efficient?

I understand what fork does and what it returns, and basic things like checking the value of pid to change my program flow.

Below is my implementation, but as I started drawing out what each parent and child does, it made no sense to do it this way, as I'd rather have each child fork() again until the total number of partitions is reached (just like a binary tree). search() is just an iterative search function.

```
int start = 0;
int end = partition_size - 1;
int found = -1;
while(end < size){
   pit_t pid = fork();

   if (pid > 0){
       found = search(the_list, start, end, target);
   }
   if (pid  == 0){
       start  = end+ 1;
       end += partition_size;
       found = search(the_list, start, end, target);
   }

   start += partition_size;
   end += partition_size;

}
```

Comment: By the time fork creates your new process the single process approach would probably already have finished.

Comment: If we are talking sizes of only ~2000, no need to use a fork.

Comment: The tricky part of this is how the child process will send the result back to the parent.

Comment: You should only call `search()` in the child processes. `pid > 0` means it's the parent process.

Comment: @Fredrik This is for an assignment I have, but it definitely would finish faster in the single process.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I determine the optimal sub-array size when the array size exceeds 1000?

If you know your available processing units (e.g. expected number of free cores) you can calculate how many children can run in parallel. More than that would make it less efficient, not more.

> How can I make use of fork() so that this implementation of iterative search is more efficient?

With those numbers (i.e. 1000, 2000, etc.) it won't be more efficient than a single threaded iterative solution.

With bigger numbers it can be more efficient by forking several children to run concurrently. You can calculate the amount of children to fork according to the processing units you've got.